# Post and bbpress - link discuss on forum

Tags: bbpress

i would like to have in every post a link to bbpress, for example:

"Discuss it on Forum"

But, how to link it up? Using tags, categories? I don't know how i can do it.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter is what you are looking for?

Comment: i don't know.. I mean to link a post up to forum's category or topic. Discussing the same object in the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `[bbp-single-topic id=$topic_id]` shortcode to link to an individual topic that you create manually.

http://codex.bbpress.org/shortcodes/

Or your other option is to wait for bbPress 2.6 that will include a feature that will allow you to replace WordPress post comments with bbPress topics.

http://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2498